# reporting services ssrs pie chart is showing only one value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have this problem. Pie chart is showing only one value and not the other one.

As you can see in design i have two values

Design:
[image]

Preview
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean it is not showing the label for Overdue series as for In Time which is 530?

Comment: Thank first of all for the prompt answer.

It should have shown the value of the Ovredue not only the In time
in this specific case is 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the Overdue series and select `Show Data Labels`.

[image]

Or select the Overdue series and press F4 to see properties, expand label property and set:

In Label property use: `=Sum(Fields!Overdue.Value)`
In Visible select: `True`

[image]

You will get this in preview:

[image]

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Thank you very much!! That fixed my issue, thank you again

Comment: @GPan, you are welcome. If my answer solved your issue you can select it as correct or up-vote it. [How to select an answer as correct](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)